# Annoying Glitch when inserting symbols

Tags: symbolic, symbols

Anybody else had this glitch when inserting symbols

[image]

This should be `::Delta`

Comment: Don't see this on v12.2.0 Win7-x64. Esc d Esc gives `δ`

Comment: You have only partially entered the symbol. Click on the expansion arrow for the window to see the other selections available.

Comment: @BobHanlon that might be the case but how does `\[VeryThinSpace]` even come close to `::Delta`?